# Flutter Feature Single Container in Widget Tree on first open

Tags: flutter, dart

When the user opens the app for the first time i would like to **explain some features**. To do so i designed a **bottom sheet** which appears in the bottom part of the screen. At the same time i want to **darken most of the screen**, with the exception of the container I want to explain.
I attached a example picture below...
***Thanks for any help!***

```
class Feature extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FeatureState createState() => _FeatureState();
}

class _FeatureState extends State<Feature> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      if (isFirstOpen)
        showBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (context) => BottomInfo());
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 30, 50, 30),
          ),
          itemCount: 3,
        ));
  }
}
```

[image: example picture]

Comment: You have to put some code to show what you've done so far... a simple design really doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Update: OverlayEntry helped me to create those hints.